# FFMEG won't transcode from 7.1 AAC to 7.1 eAC3

Tags: mac, audio, ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding

Have been trying to convert my video files from AAC to eAC3. I don't have Adobe Media Encoder, and am trying to do this with FFMPEG. Any help is

Note: I have copies of the following software that may be of use:

- Logic Pro 10.1.1
- Final Cut Pro
- Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015 (without Adobe Media Encoder)
- VLC
- FFMPEG (Command Line)
- Handbrake

I have been using `ffmpeg -i input-with-aac-7.1-audio.mkv -c:a eac3 -c:v copy output-eac3.mkv` to attempt a transcode, but it forces the mixdown to 5.1

---

getting this output:

```
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
 [aac @ 0x7ff3f40c4400] Assuming an incorrectly encoded 7.1 channel layout instead of a spec-compliant 7.1(wide) layout, use -strict 1 to decode according to the specification instead.
```

EDIT: used the `-strict 1` -- it didn't force the stream into 7.1

Thanks for any help in advance,

B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg's eAC3 encoder does not support more than 6 channels. See bug report: [Support >6 channels in E-AC-3 audio](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3595)